# How to install mod_wsgi to specific python version in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, server, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to install the mod_wsgi module in apache in my Ubuntu server but I need it to be specifically for version 2.7.13 in Python.For whatever reason every time I run sudo apt-get install  libapache2-mod-wsgi it installs the mod_wsgi module for Python 2.7.12.I'm doing all of this because I'm running into a weird python version issue.When I run one of my python Scripts in my server terminal it works perfectly with version 2.7.13.In Apache however the script doesn't work.I managed to figure out that my Apache is running version 2.7.12 and I think this is the issue.Still can't figure out how to change that apache python version yet though.

Comment: Define "script doesn't work" so we can fix the actual problem. Mixing patch level revisions of Python with mod_wsgi is usually not a problem as explained in the documentation. See http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/installation-issues.html#python-patch-level-mismatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually Figured it out.The problem was that I had 2 versions of Python 2.7 installed in my server(2.7.12 and 2.7.13) so the definitions of one were conflicting with the other.Solved it when I completely  removed Python 2.7.13 from the server.